# Unable to include a template

Tags: templates, template-hierarchy, get-template-part

On the `home.php`, which is in the same folder where `style.css` is kept I am try to call a template:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'home-default' ); ?>
```

1. *template-parts* is a folder which is in the root folder same where we have *style.css*, like

---

```
- theme-directory
  -- template-parts
     --- content-home-default.php
  -- style.css
  -- home.php
```

3. Template is:  `content-home-default.php` in template-parts, which is in the root folder

But this is not able to fetch this template. I am a beginner so perhaps doing some nonsensical mistake. Can someone please guide me.

Comment: Your path seems to be correct. Make sure that whatever you are writing here is exactly same in your theme/plugin. If the folder `template-parts` is correct than I am unable to find any issue. I hope you are not doing this → `'/template-parts/content'`

Comment: What did you mean by **template-parts is a folder in style.css**?

`home.php` is used to list blog posts. Are you sure that `home.php` is being called?

Comment: I believe she meant to says same as the root folder where style.css is kept.

Comment: Yes, @ The WP novice is right.

Comment: Check for spelling mistakes otherwise rest be assured that you are including it correctly. I couldn't find any issue here.

Comment: I have re-checked as you have suggested, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you sure you're viewing home.php on the front-end? Do other changes to the template appear?

Comment: Yes, when I bring it in root folder and write this: `<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'home-default' ); ?>` then it works. but I wanted to organize things better.

Comment: If I transfer `home.php` in this folder: template-parts can WP recognize `home.php`?

Comment: No `home.php` should be in the root folder.

Comment: Certain templates need to be in the root folder, see https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/